# Can I use an image in my modeline lighter?

Tags: mode-line, images, text-properties

My modeline is cluttered. Can I make it display pictures instead of mode names?

I could use unicode Emoji (such as  for Python or  for Coq), but some machines on which I use my Emacs config do not have the right fonts pre-installed (ideally, I'd also like to reuse this technique in a mode that I'm writing, so I can't expect users to have the right font setup).

I tried adding an `:image` display property to the modeline lighter of a toy minor-mode, but nothing appeared in the modeline:

```
(define-minor-mode my/test-mode
  "Test mode."
  :lighter (propertize " " 'display '(image :type imagemagick
                                             :file "/home/clement/.emacs.d/rooster.png")))
```

[image: TWEmoji rooster (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/twitter/twemoji/gh-pages/72x72/1f413.png)]

Comment: Is there a way to bring the fonts into your config?

Comment: Yes, it totally is possible to do that.  See nyan-mode.  Could it be that the image is too large to be displayed properly?

Comment: @wasamasa, Great point! Do you know how nyan-mode does it?

Comment: How to replace major-mode string in mode-line with this icon?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The mode line is rendered from a list of segments, each of which come with their own special rules.  See [Mode Line Data](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Data.html) for the details.  The symbol section contains a crucial hint to make your code work:

> Unless SYMBOL is marked as “risky” (i.e., it has a non-‘nil’
>   ‘risky-local-variable’ property), all text properties specified in
>   SYMBOL’s value are ignored.  This includes the text properties of
>   strings in SYMBOL’s value, as well as all ‘:eval’ and ‘:propertize’
>   forms in it.  (The reason for this is security: non-risky variables
>   could be set automatically from file variables without prompting
>   the user.)

I suspect [nyan-mode is doing it in a less than ideal way](https://github.com/TeMPOraL/nyan-mode/blob/master/nyan-mode.el#L240), so here's my minimal example:

```
(defvar my-nyan-mode-lighter
  (list " " (propertize ":3" 'display
                        `(image :type imagemagick
                                :file ,(expand-file-name "~/nyan.png")))))
(put 'my-nyan-mode-lighter 'risky-local-variable t)

(define-minor-mode my-nyan-mode
  "Nyan mode"
  :lighter my-nyan-mode-lighter)

(my-nyan-mode)
```

The reason why I use a list of a space and an image is because it is convention to start a lighter with a space for separating it from the preceding ones.

Comment: Actually, did you try this in `emacs -Q`? It works great with smart-mode-line enabled, but I can't make it work when I start from a bare Emacs.

Comment: Huh, you're right.  I'll check what else is missing.

Comment: OK, I've figured it out.  Apparently that package just uses strings inside a format string whereas the real deal walks through the mode line segments individually and does only recognize strings that are propertized from start to end, so I've went for a list of two strings to have a separator.

Comment: Brillian, many thanks! The list tricks the mode line formatter into not applying the top-level `:propertize` of the default `mode-line-format`.

Comment: @wasamasa Wow, that's nice. Now when you mouse over the image, there is a generic menu ; how would one put entries in it? Just a simple string as a mouse hover message would be fine, too.

Comment: Bonus question: How do you make a link (mouse-1) from this icon to, say, the `*scratch*` buffer?

Comment: Comments are not for questions, if you want me to answer something, hand in a question please.

Answer (score 5):

Good question.

You might try using something like this as the lighter: `(concat " " (propertize " " 'display (create-image img-file)))`, where `img-file` is the name of your image file.  (The first space char is just to separate this lighter from the previous one.)

Well, I just tried, using this code, but it did **not** work for me. You might try fiddling a bit more with it. Dunno whether it is possible.

```el
(defvar my-lighter-string
        (concat " " (propertize " " 'display (create-image "/path/to/an/image/file.png"))))

(define-minor-mode foo "..." nil my-lighter-string)
```

The lighter just shows as an ordinary space char -- the `display` property does not seem to be respected.

If you don't get a good answer to this question, consider filing an Emacs enhancement request, using `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

One thing you can certainly do is to use one or two Unicode characters in the mode-line string.  And you can use chars that are, in effect, graphics.